# Simplify Boolean Equation to MUX

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra

I have this Boolean equation which my professor told me it is possible to simplify to a MUX 4X1 but I can't do it. Would love some help!

\$f(A, B, C, D) = A'B'C'D' + AB'CD' + A'BC'D' + ABCD\$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: A 4:1 MUX has 2 address bits, your function has 4inputs. A 16:1 MUX easy but big.

Comment: What have you tried? Happy to help but you won't learnif we just do ypur homework for you.

Comment: It can be simplified to a 4:1 MUX, two NOT gates and three AND gates. Maybe that is what he meant?

Answer (score 0):

The boolean expression is impossible for a 4:1 multiplexer, because boolean expression of a multiplexer is a combination of selector pins and inputs. You have missed you selector pins in the expression, I guess.
a possible expression can be, 
Q = a'b'A + a'bB + ab'C + abD where a, b are the selector pins and A,B,C,D are the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply C and D to the select inputs of a 4 way multiplexor you can use apply A' to the 00 input, AB' to the 10 input and AB to the 11 input. There may be a more optimum solution.

Regards
Ian Mccrum

__